# .Net core web api - How to implement PUT, POST and DELETE methods in controller?

Tags: entity-framework, post, asp.net-core-webapi, put, one-to-one

In this, I have implemented(for practice purpose) one to one relationship between two entities Student and Department where each department can have one student in it. Student table has DepartmentId as foreign key. [HttpGet] and [HttpGet({"id"})] methods are implemented accordingly by using Include() to include department entity in student. How PUT, POST and DELETE methods can be implemented in StudentController.cs file so that, similar to GET requests, department entity is included.

**Student.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Students.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="varchar(50)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Department.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Students.Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(20)")]
        public string Dep { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StudentContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Students.Models
{
    public class StudentContext:DbContext
    {
        public StudentContext(DbContextOptions<StudentContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StudentController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Students.Models;

namespace Students.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly StudentContext _context;

        public StudentsController(StudentContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Students
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetStudents()
        {
            return await _context.Students.Include(d => d.Department).ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Students/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> GetStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = await _context.Students.Include(d => d.Department).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.SId == id);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return student;
        }

        // PUT: api/Students/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutStudent(int id, Student student)
        {
            if (id != student.SId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!StudentExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Students
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudent(Student student)
        {
            _context.Students.Add(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetStudent", new { id = student.SId }, student);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Students/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> DeleteStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = await _context.Students.FindAsync(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Students.Remove(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return student;
        }

        private bool StudentExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Students.Any(e => e.SId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo like below:

1.POST(Be sure that there is no need to pass any id):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudent(Student student)
{
    _context.Departments.Add(student.Department);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    _context.Students.Add(student);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetStudent", new { id = student.SId }, student);
}
```

Postman:
[image]

2.PUT:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutStudent(int id, Student student)
{
    if (id != student.SId)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    _context.Departments.Update(student.Department);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!StudentExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return NoContent();
}
```

Postman:
[image]
3.DELETE:

Be the same as yours.

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> DeleteStudent(int id)
{
    var student = await _context.Students.FindAsync(id);
    if (student == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    _context.Students.Remove(student);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return student;
}
```